# Batch file password generator not giving consistent output

Tags: passwords, batch-file, cmd.exe

i have this piece of code. Its basically a random password generator. i enter the password length i want say "10" then i get a random password generated with 10 letters numbers and symbols and its saved in a txt file. The issue happens when i create a second one. If i again want a password length of "10" but it only gives me a password of say 3 or 4. it depends. Any ideas on where i went wrong on this ?. any help is much appreciated.

```
@Echo Off
mode con: cols=70 lines=25
:start
color 8a
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
echo --------                  Password Generator                   -------
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
Echo Hello %username%
set /P lengthnumberuser="What length do you want your password to be?:
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _RNDLength=%lengthnumberuser%
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789%%$$@@**
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
echo.
echo.
echo.
cls
Echo Password is: !_RndAlphaNum!
set /p _detail=Please Record a description for this password:
echo.
echo %date%---%_detail%----!_RndAlphaNum! >> RandPass.txt
echo Password Saved with Details to RandPass.txt for future reference.
echo.
echo.
set /p _newpass= Would you like to create another password ?[y/n]:
cls

If /i "%_newpass%"== "y" GOTO :start else :end

:end
```

Comment: Try replacing `%_RNDLength%` with `!_RNDLength!`

Comment: Hi i changed that here `If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop` and still no luck gave 10 first time around ..then only this 5 digits second time

Comment: You might also need to change `Set /a _count+=1` to `Set /a !_count!+=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like overlong variable names, but this works:

```
@Echo Off
mode con: cols=70 lines=25
:start
color 8a
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
echo --------                  Password Generator                   -------
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
Echo Hello %username%
set /P len="What length do you want your password to be?:
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$@*"
Set CharsCnt=65
Set "Pass="
For /L %%c in (1,1,%Len%) do (
  Set /a Pnt=!Random! %% CharsCnt
  Call Set "Pass=!Pass!%%Chars:~!Pnt!,1%%"
)
cls
Echo Password is: %Pass%
set /p _detail=Please Record a description for this password:
echo.
echo %date%---%_detail%----%Pass% >> RandPass.txt
echo Password Saved with Details to RandPass.txt for future reference.
echo.
echo.
set /p _newpass= Would you like to create another password ?[y/n]:
cls
If /i "%_newpass%"== "y" GOTO :start
:end
```

BTW: outputting several empty lines and then a cls doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: tried your input and the output i got was this both should have been 10 chars long                                                                                                    1st attempt = j5@llZ2v%Chars:~37,1 
, 2nd attempt = GrXlqKMpj

Comment: I think the percent sign is creating trouble. I removed it from chars. When it is in the Password it would have to be escaped to not be interpreted as enclosing an additional variable.